# Evaluate a Cypress configuration file

Tags: node.js, cypress

In my build scripts I need to evaluate a Cypress configuration file. I'm using the following script:

```js
let appdata = process.env.LOCALAPPDATA;
let version = `11.0.1`;
let src = `${appdata}/Cypress/Cache/${version}/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/data-context/src`;
const DataContext = require(`${src}/DataContext.js`).DataContext;
const ProjectConfigManager  = require(`${src}/data/ProjectConfigManager.js`).ProjectConfigManager;

(async() => {
  const ctx = new DataContext({
      schema: null,
      schemaCloud: null,
      modeOptions: "run",
      appApi: {},
      localSettingsApi: {},
      authApi: {

      } ,
      configApi: {
      },
      projectApi: {

      } ,
      electronApi: {
      } ,
      browserApi: {

      },
    })

  let configManager = new ProjectConfigManager({
       ctx,
       configFile: 'C:\\work\\sample\\sample.config.ts',
       projectRoot: 'C:\\work\\sample',
       handlers: [],
       hasCypressEnvFile: false,
       eventRegistrar: null/*new EventRegistrar()*/,
       onError: (error) => {},
       onInitialConfigLoaded: () => {},
       onFinalConfigLoaded: () => Promise.resolve(),
       refreshLifecycle: () => Promise.resolve(),
     })

  configManager.configFilePath = "sample.config.ts"
  configManager.setTestingType('e2e')

  let cfg = await configManager.getConfigFileContents()

  console.log(JSON.stringify(cfg));

})();
```

It works well for `Cypress 10` version.
However, `Cypress 11` has introduced some changes that break this script. Though I adjusted the paths, I'm still unable to make it work again.
It currently fails with this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\mbolotov\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\11.0.1\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\graphql\index'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

How can I fix this problem (without making changes to the Cypress installation)?

OR

Is there any other way to evaluate a Cypress configuration file (say from the command line) and obtain its values?

Answer (score 5):

The exact usage is unclear to me, but making some assumptions - a nodejs script in the `/scripts` folder of the project can compile and resolve the config using the Cypress module API.

It would need a test to run, a "null-test" can be generated from inside the script.

**Note**, the null-test must conform to the spec pattern of the project (below it's the std `.cy.js`)

```js
const cypress = require('cypress')
const fs = require('fs')

fs.writeFileSync('../cypress/e2e/null-test.cy.js', 'it("", ()=>{})')

cypress.run({
  project: '..',
  spec: '../cypress/e2e/null-test.cy.js',
  quiet: true
}).then(results => {
  if (results.status === 'failed') {
    console.log(results)
  } else {
    console.log(results.config.resolved)      // output resolved config
  }
})
```

I haven't attempted to duplicate everything you have in your code, as it's using Cypress internals and not publicly documented.

Comment: Unfortunately, the spec pattern is one the values that I have to discover when evaluating the config file. 
So we cannot make any assumptions about what it can be and thus it's impossible to use any dummy spec.

Comment: You can set the specPattern in the API call, then the result.config is everything but the specPattern.

Comment: Getting `specPattern` is a must. So I have to find another solution

Answer (score 4):

This may be because of [Changelog 11.0.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#11-0-0)

> We have also massively improved our startup performance by **shipping a snapshot of our binary instead of the source files**.

Looking inside the cache folder for **v10.11.0** (`${process.env.CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER}/10.11.0/Cypress/resources/app`), the `/node_modules` is fully populated and `/node_modules/graphql/index.js` exists.

But in **v11.0.1** `/node_modules/graphql` is not fully populated.

Comment: so how can I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to do - what exactly is "Evaluate a Cypress configuration file", are you checking for errors?

Comment: not really, I just need to get the values ​​defined the config

Comment: Ok, so given the current format of `cypress.config.js` - pass that through some code to make something akin to the old `cypress.json` format. Do you need any config resolved during startup in `setupNodeEvents()`?

Comment: The obvious thing to try if above is correct, reinstall the node_modules.

Comment: The package.json in cache has no dependencies listed, but the github repo does - I presume you could use that.

Comment: If you don't need changes from `setupNodeEvents()` if any, it looks like it's enough to run `const config = require('./cypress.config.js')`

Comment: I need the resolved config at a build step of my code (outside of the Cypress run). 
Simple `require` will not work for all the cases. E.g. it won't work for es modules and TS code.
So I think the ideal approach would embed into the Cypress call chain for getting the resolved config.

Comment: `reinstall the node_modules` - how can I do that? I ran `npm install` at `${process.env.CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER}/10.11.0/Cypress/resources/app` level. It just removed almost all the packages including `@packages` (where `data-context` is located). So this way is definitely not working

Comment: Did you look at the package.json in that folder? See above, you would need the full dependency list from github (matching versions).

Comment: Also those config classes are also in another folder (other than @packages) but I can't remember what it was now.